# PhpDocx Gettemplatevariables not working as expexted

Tags: php, phpdocx

I am using `phpdocx-premium-12.5-ns`. I created a document with variables like `%%variable%%`, then I try the below code:

```
 require_once 'classes/CreateDocx.php';

 $docx = new CreateDocxFromTemplate('document.docx');

 $docx->setTemplateSymbol('%%', '%%');

 print_r($docx->getTemplateVariables());
```

But it does not return anything, if I add a variable like `${variable}` it is returned as `${variable}`

If I set the symbol  `$docx->setTemplateSymbol('${', '}')` it works normally and returns the `variable`.

My question: how can I use this variable `%%variable%%` and use the `%%` as a template symbol to get all the existing variables?

As I checked in the code of 'CreateDocxFromTemplate.php' class they call `extractVariablesDistinctSymbols` where they `preg_match` this pattern only: `\$(?:\{|[^{$]*\>\{)[^}$]*\}`

Answer (score 0):

i get the answer from phpdocx

> The character or symbol used to wrap template variables may be:
>
> ```
> The same at the beginning and the end (setting only $templateSymbolStart): $VAR$, #VAR#... A single 1 byte character.
> Different at the beginning and the end: ${VAR}. phpdocx requires using ${ } to wrap placeholders that don't use the same symbol at the
> ```
>
> beginning and the end, to use other symbols the public static variable
> CreateDocxFromTemplate::$regExprVariableSymbols must be customized.
>
> If your template is using a symbol to wrap placeholders with more than
> 1 byte character, as it's the case of %%, or different at the
> beginning and the end you need to customize the public static variable
> CreateDocxFromTemplate::$regExprVariableSymbols. A simple sample:
>
> ```
> CreateDocxFromTemplate::$regExprVariableSymbols = '%(.*)%(.*)%(.*)%';
> $docx->setTemplateSymbol('%%');
> ```
>
> We recommend using a single 1 byte character or ${} to wrap
> placeholders, so you don't need to generate a custom
> CreateDocxFromTemplate::$regExprVariableSymbols. This uses regular
> expressions, so when using protected characters they must be escaped.